# TypeScript settings not picked up by editor, but works on command line/terminal

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, languageservice

I'm trying to work on this TypeScript project. I've written a `tsconfig.json`, and when I try running from the command line, everything works fine.

However, when I try editing the project's files in Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio, Sublime, or WebStorm, those settings don't appear to be getting applied. Here's a few things that are special about this `tsconfig.json` in case it helps:

- It uses the `strict` flag.
- It uses `noImplicitAny` and `strictNullChecks` for good measure.
- It uses path mapping (i.e. the `paths` and `baseUrl` fields).

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

## First: make sure your `tsconfig.json` is free of syntax errors

You might add a field to your configuration file, but JSON is a very picky language, so while you may have previously run with `tsc`, you might not have noticed your `tsconfig.json` was recently broken.

## Second: make sure that your files are being included in the project configuration

First, check that your `tsconfig.json` is including your files by running `tsc` using the `--listFiles` flag.

If the files are not listed by `tsc --listFiles`, you can add them to your `tsconfig.json` using a set of top-level fields:

---

### The `include` & `exclude` fields

The easiest way is to specify a series of patterns (specifically "globs") to match folders & files using the **`"include"`** and **`"exclude"`** fields. This can be an entire folder like `./src`.

For example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {/*...*/},
    "include": ["./src"]
}
```

---

### The `files` field

You can specify the list of files using the **`"files"`** field. If you have a single file that transitively imports everything else, then you can just list that entry-point. But *make sure you end up actually importing those files*.

For example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {/*...*/},
    "files": ["./src/index.ts"]
}
```